# how to write makefile that adds libraries after source

Tags: c++, makefile

I have been supplied with the following makefile:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -g -O2
LDFLAGS=-ltbb

EXE=$(basename $(wildcard *.cc))

all: $(EXE)

clean:
    rm -fr $(EXE) *.dSYM
```

I am new to makefiles and In order to get it working in Ubuntu, I need to modify it such that the LDFLAGS comes after the source file in the compile command. How can I do this? My attempt is as follows:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -g -O2
LDFLAGS=-ltbb

SRCS=$(wildcard *.cc)
EXES=$(subst .cc,,$(SRCS))

all: $(EXES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRCS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXES)

clean:
    rm -fr $(EXE) *.dSYM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries should be added to LDLIBS instead of LDFLAGS. Try this in your original makefile:

```
LDLIBS=-ltbb
```

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) for reference.

Comment: Ah, that worked! Thanks for your solution and for the helpful reference.